# Capturing SASS variables using RegEX

Tags: regex

I'd like to create a RegEX to capture SASS variables, but only "px" SASS variables...

**My variables :**

```
$navbar-link-bg: #a1a1a8;
$navbar-link-bg-hover: lighten($navbar-link-bg, 10%);
$navbar-sub-link-padding: 5px;
$navbar-sub-radius: 0;
$navbar-link-color: #000;
$navbar-link-color-hover: #000;
$navbar-height: 30px;
$background: url('../images/common/bg.png');
```

**What I'd like to get :**

```
['navbar-sub-link-padding', 'navbar-height']
```

**My RegEXP that doesn't work :**

`[$][a-zA-Z-]+[:].+[px]`

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? I just tried it and it matched a px variable. Though the `[px]` should not be in brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the Job :

```
pattern = "\$(.+?):.*px"
```

For reference please have a look : [regex reference](https://regex101.com/r/T5jWJn/1)

Comment: .* means any number of characters , Have a look at the reference link , Let me know if it doesn't works

Comment: Yes, any number including zero - would it make sense to have a variable value with just `px` and nothing before it?

Comment: @tonymx227 what's the programming language you are using ? , if it's python group 1 will give you the exact required text